# Sum the total of a column in excel and paste the sum to a different workbook

Tags: excel, vba, sum

So I have a workbook with a macro, i will use the macro to open a different workbook called 'filename' once I have opened this 2nd workbook I will sum column AJ then with that value I would like to copy and paste the total value to cell C29 on the first workbook all in excel and VBA.

```vb
Sub vba_open_workbook()

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

filename = Range("G11")

Workbooks.Open filename
Workbooks(1).Activate

Range("C29") = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("AJ:AJ"))

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Get Column Sum From Closed Workbook

```
Option Explicit

Sub AcquireSum()

    'Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic ' ?
    
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = dwb.Sheets("Sheet1") ' adjust!
    Dim dCell As Range: Set dCell = dws.Range("C29")
    
    Dim sFilePath As String: sFilePath = dws.Range("G11").Value
    
    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = Workbooks.Open(sFilePath)
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = swb.Sheets("Sheet1") ' adjust!
    Dim sSum As Variant: sSum = Application.Sum(sws.Columns("AJ"))
    swb.Close SaveChanges:=False ' it was just read from
    
    If IsError(sSum) Then
        MsgBox "Errors in column. Sum not acquired.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    dCell.Value = sSum
    
    MsgBox "Sum acquired.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you.
Just one more part - the name of the sheet in the second part of the macro will be different each day as it uses todays date. however it will alwasy be the first sheet in the workbook. Is it possible to use 'Sheet number 1' or automatically update with the date?

Comment: date format would be yyyymmdd

Comment: If it's the first sheet, use index `1` without double quotes: `.Sheets(1)`.

Answer (score 0):

You should always use **explicit** referencing when using the `Range`-object.

If not: it refers to the *active* sheet. That means that your current code inserts ths sum on the same sheet from which it takes the values to be summed.

**IMPORTANT**: You have to replace the XXXX parts with the worksheet names of your workbooks.

```vb
Sub vba_open_workbook()

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

Dim rgSource As Range
Set rgSource = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("XXXX").Range("AJ:AJ")

Dim Filename As String
Filename = Thisworkbook.Range("G11")

Dim wbTarget As Workbook
Set wbTarget = Workbooks.Open(Filename)

Dim rgTarget As Range
Set rgTarget = wbTarget.Worksheets("XXXX").Range("C29")

rgTarget.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(rgSource)

End Sub
```

Comment: I get an error saying 'Subscript out of range'

Comment: Now it wont run and says ' method or data member not found'. sorry i have no idea how to use vba :)

Comment: Did you replace the "XXXX" with your worksheet names

Comment: Yes -----------

Comment: on which row do you get the error?

Comment: first row will not run as it says

"Compile error:

Method or data member not found"

Comment: Did you keep the quotation marks around the sheet names? - But that would result in a different error. Can you upload an image of your code - there must be a typo somewhere

Comment: `ThisWorkbook` doesn't have a `.Range` method or property. But I'm quite sure you have mixed up the workbooks. Maybe read the question more carefully.